# ASP Razor- displaying video in a background

Tags: asp.net, video, razor

I want to display a video clip and on top of it display various items, like logo.

I installed "ASP.NET Web Helpers Library" which allowed me to display various types of videos.

I will be using .wmv files so my approach is:

```
<div style="z-index: -1">
        @Video.MediaPlayer(
        width : "400",
        height : "600",
        path: "Media/Sample.wmv",
        uiMode : "none",
        autoStart: true,
        playCount: 2,
        stretchToFit: true,
        enableContextMenu: false,
        mute: true

    )    
</div>
```

it works fine but I cannot display anything on top of it.

Questions:

- is it the best approach to display video in a background?
- if so, how can I make it work the way I want?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `position: relative` or `position: absolute` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `Webmatrix` is that when you press F12 to see how your `*.cshtml` works is that `<video>` tag will not be displayed properly if it is supposed to play video file located on the HDD.

Once you link to video file located on the internet it works fine.

So my problem is not a problem after all because after publishing you can link to video file located on your host using `http` link.

Not sure if it works as fast as it would be linked using local path but it works good enough for me.